# Import from SQL Server Express into SQL Server CE

Tags: sql, sql-server-ce, sql-server-express

I'm using SQL Server 2005 Express as a database in my desktop application. 
My question is how to import from that database (which include table and stored procedure) into SQL Server CE.

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server CE doesn't support stored procedure.

Find out the comparison between CE and Express edition in the following link contains Local Data Feature Comparison.

http://download.microsoft.com/download/A/4/7/A47B7B0E-976D-4F49-B15D-F02ADE638EBE/Compact_Express_Comparison.doc